# android spinner ripple effect on target 19

Tags: android, android-spinner

Hello all I want to do like below image [image]

for that i have done is, I made a custom view for row items

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       >
          <com.andexert.library.RippleView
      android:id="@+id/more1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >
        <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tvspinnerlist"
        android:text="Spinner List"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
       android:padding="4dp"
       android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium" 
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:ellipsize="marquee" />
        </com.andexert.library.RippleView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

and this is my spinner

```
<com.andexert.library.RippleView
  android:id="@+id/more1"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       >           
   <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spnOperator"
     style="?android:label"
   android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
   android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_weight="0.17" /> 
</com.andexert.library.RippleView>
```

For this i am facing 2 problems...

1. on click on right hand side button only(triangle btn) spinners opens(not opening on spinner click)
2. spinner does not close on item selection

Thanks,

Comment: you should have formatted your xml before posting

Comment: why don't you load http://rey5137.com/material/ library?i have made the same spinner as it is in the image you provided..i could post my answer if you like..

Answer (score 0):

You basically have two ways:

1. Create RippleDrawable in res/values-v21/ and set that to be the background on the Spinner `spinner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spinner_background);`.
2. Do this using Theme. Define the spinner like this: (somewhere in you activity.xml)
       
   **ripple_background.xml**

   ```
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <item>
           <ripple android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight">
              <item>
                 <shape>
                     <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
                 </shape>
              </item>
           </ripple>
       </item>
   </selector>
   ```